# How to run methods in onCreate() without button click

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Right now, I have to click the button twice when my app starts up to show the data. I want to
open the app with the data displayed. Without using onclick method, data from volley api request doesnt load. I am using a recyclerviw to bind data to views. I've even tried creating a seperate class for getting data but only works with button clicks.

```
    private ArrayList<Stocks_data_model> exampleList;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    static String t;
    static String n;
    static String p;
    static String c;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mQueue = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
        exampleList = new ArrayList<>();


        findViewById(R.id._button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                     my_func(exampleList);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        //real data
    }


    public  void my_func(ArrayList mAr){
//         exampleList = new ArrayList<>();

        String _url = "";
        // TODO: Handle error
        //                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "[NETWORK ERROR]\nCheck Data Connection...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        JsonObjectRequest req_Gainers2 = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, _url, null, response -> {
                    try {
                        Log.d("tag", "working");

                        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                        JSONArray gainers = response.getJSONArray("mostGainerStock");
                        JSONObject myData = gainers.getJSONObject(i);
                        String _name = myData.getString("companyName");
                        String _ticker = myData.getString("ticker");
                        String _price = myData.getString("price");
                        double _changes = myData.getDouble("changes");
                        String _change_percent = myData.getString("changesPercentage");

                        mAr.add(new Stocks_data_model(_ticker, _name, _price, _change_percent));
//                         exampleList.add(new Stocks_data_model(_ticker, "name", "$10.99", _change_percent));

                            t = _ticker;
                            n=_name;
                            p=_price;
                            c=_change_percent;


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
//         mQueue.add(req_Gainers2);
        mQueue.add(req_Gainers2);

        buildRecyclerView();

    }
}
```

After some feedbacks, heres the new onCreate method i tried that is still giving the same issue.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         mQueue = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
         exampleList = new ArrayList<>();


         findViewById(R.id._button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 try {
                      my_func(exampleList);
                      buildRecyclerView();

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         });
```

Comment: I presume this is because `buildRecyclerView` is called before the network request has had a chance to complete, whereas you probably meant for it to be called after?

Comment: Bassically what @HenryTwist says is right, you are making an async call with volley, and you should build/notify change data your recycleView inside the response not outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you want to load your data without clicking the button and you are putting all the code responsible for retrieving and displaying data inside the OnClickListener of the button.
If you want to display data when the app loads, take all the code out of OnClickListener.

You are not seeing data until a double click is because, as soon as you click, the data retrieval starts asynchronously and codes keeps running and reaches to setup the recyclerview. But the data is not yet retrieved. That's why the recyclerview is displaying nothing.

In your subsequent click on the button, data retrieval is completed and recyclerview is able to display the data.

To fix it, we need to wait until the data is retrieved.. This can be achieved by many ways.
A quick fix can be calling your `buildRecyclerView()` function at the last line of try block inside `my_func()`.

Comment: I called `buildRecyclerView()` in the try, under the my function but still requires 2 clicks to display. I keep the code inside an onclick method because otherwise, nothing happens just empty recyclerview as you mentioned, onclick helps me retrieve data. since the api call itself is async, using try/catch, i don't really need another tyr/catch in oncreate but used it hoping it would help. Please advice me further on how to resolve this issue. I can post the new code

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't mention which try block you should call `buildRecyclerView()` from. Call that function from the last line of try block inside the `my_func()`

Comment: yoooo bro you're a fucking hero. been on this for over a month and just deicded to ask my own question since none was working and now, an hour later, i got the answer. i truly appreciate you man, thank you.

Comment: Glad to know it worked. You may mark my answer as accepted answer if it solved your problem. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data without click take the method call outside the click Listener.

```
    my_func(exampleList);
```

Before my_fun() method  run your buildRecyclerView(); method in oncreate.

Then in last line of try block notify the adapter of recyclerView to update the data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call your method in `onCreate`. For example :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     mQueue = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
     exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
     
     thisIsMyFunction();
     }


public void thisIsMyFunction() {
     try {
          my_func(exampleList);
          buildRecyclerView();

     } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
     //you can add all the code you want to execute here
}
```